# Exchange Server 2013 EXPR Section missing from autodiscover

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2013, autodiscovery

We have a client who is having an issue with their autodiscover.  They have an Exchange Server 2013 with CU1.  After attempting to run an update on the server (Win 2k8R2) I needed to revert the changes, so I fell back to the snapshot I took before I began the maintenance.

After I rolled back to the previous snapshot, Exchange's autodiscover is no longer publishing the EXPR section of the Autodiscover.xml file. We can see the EXPR when we run "Get-OutlookProvider".

Here is the output of the autodiscover on a client computer:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
  <Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a">
    <User>
      <DisplayName>Administrator</DisplayName>
      <LegacyDN>/o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=21ef283c661344649ec85ae2dd46109b-Admin</LegacyDN>
      <AutoDiscoverSMTPAddress>Administrator@*********.org</AutoDiscoverSMTPAddress>
      <DeploymentId>bc6368b5-d956-4619-bced-e5b973712f93</DeploymentId>
    </User>
    <Account>
      <AccountType>email</AccountType>
      <Action>settings</Action>
      <MicrosoftOnline>False</MicrosoftOnline>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>EXCH</Type>
        <Server>79f33240-cbb4-4bfe-a5a2-eca20a411fc8@********.org</Server>
        <ServerDN>/o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=79f33240-cbb4-4bfe-a5a2-eca20a411fc8@*************.org</ServerDN>
        <ServerVersion>73C0826C</ServerVersion>
        <MdbDN>/o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=79f33240-cbb4-4bfe-a5a2-eca20a411fc8@***********.org/cn=Microsoft Private MDB</MdbDN>
        <AD>ests-rpl-dc248.ests.local</AD>
        <ServerExclusiveConnect>off</ServerExclusiveConnect>
      </Protocol>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>WEB</Type>
      </Protocol>
      <PublicFolderInformation>
        <SmtpAddress>E***@*********.org</SmtpAddress>
      </PublicFolderInformation>
    </Account>
  </Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

We have tried running "Remove-OutlookProvider EXCH" and then adding it back by running "New-OutlookProvider EXCH", but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that the EXPR is missing, then the commands you need to run should be:

```
Remove-OutlookProvider EXPR
New-OutlookProvider EXPR
```